# What happens to my Long Put (Bought Puts) when company file chapter 11

Tags: options, call-options, put-options, option-strategies

What happens to my long put that i buy for Dec 2020 if the company files for chapter 11 in Nov 2020 or before option expiration.

Would I be able to sell those long puts to get maximum reward for those put options automatically or those options will cease to exist or trade to cash

Same question for short call (covered calls)

Will these options will be worth less and fall under chapter 11 umbrella.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How urgent is it to close put options when a company enters bankruptcy? How likely is it to have trading halted?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/102417/how-urgent-is-it-to-close-put-options-when-a-company-enters-bankruptcy-how-like)

Comment: THat has already been askwd and answered as https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/102417/how-urgent-is-it-to-close-put-options-when-a-company-enters-bankruptcy-how-like - closing as double. In short: You have a right to sell the stocks at put value. The details depend on whether the company stops trading - CHapter 11 does not necessarily mean stocks are worthless.

Comment: We do not know. Trading halt is an excahgne / company decision which we can not foresee. Value depends on what people think either.